# visual studio 2015 compile error echo VS 11 Common tools not found

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, npm

I was working on a Angular 2 application using VS 2015; By installing Npm via NuGet I'm getting this below compile error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error The command "
      IF EXIST "%VS110COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat" (
      call "%VS110COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat"
      ) ELSE (
      echo VS 11 Common Tools not found
      )
      IF EXIST "%VS120COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat" (
      call "%VS120COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat"
      ) ELSE (
      echo VS 12 Common Tools not found
      )
      set PATH=C:\DEV\Samples\Angular2\HelloWorld\packages\Npm.js.2.13.1.0\build\..\tools\;%PATH%
      "C:\DEV\Samples\Angular2\HelloWorld\packages\Npm.js.2.13.1.0\build\..\tools\npm" install
      " exited with code 1. HelloWorld
```

which causes this error? any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to some unsupported packages when running npm install. In my case it was fsevents.

Try running:
"C:\DEV\Samples\Angular2\HelloWorld\packages\Npm.js.2.13.1.0\build..\tools\npm" install

See if you get more detailed information about the error.

Also the npm.js.targets files does not include that latest versions of VS.

Try adding:

```
IF EXIST "%VS140COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat" (
  call "%VS140COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat"
  ) ELSE (
  echo VS 14 Common Tools not found
  )
  IF EXIST "%VS150COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat" (
  call "%VS150COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat"
  ) ELSE (
  echo VS 15 Common Tools not found
  )
```